# Force Windows Update to check for updates with filters to avoid certain types of updates?

Tags: windows-update, vbscript

I Need to create a program that will check for and install important updates

Would it be possible to have it only create a popup when updates are available?

Currently I am using this code to check for updates:

```
' Written in 2007 by Harry Johnston, University of Waikato, New Zealand.
' This code has been placed in the public domain.  It may be freely
' used, modified, and distributed.  However it is provided with no
' warranty, either express or implied.
'
' Exit Codes:
'   0 = scripting failure
'   1 = error obtaining or installing updates
'   2 = installation successful, no further updates to install
'   3 = reboot needed; rerun script after reboot
'
' Note that exit code 0 has to indicate failure because that is what
' is returned if a scripting error is raised.
'

Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")

Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
Set updateDownloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
Set updateInstaller = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()

Do

  WScript.Echo
  WScript.Echo "Searching for approved updates ..."
  WScript.Echo

  Set updateSearch = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

  If updateSearch.ResultCode <> 2 Then

    WScript.Echo "Search failed with result code", updateSearch.ResultCode
    WScript.Quit 1

  End If

  If updateSearch.Updates.Count = 0 Then

    WScript.Echo "There are no updates to install."
    WScript.Quit 2

  End If

  Set updateList = updateSearch.Updates

  For I = 0 to updateSearch.Updates.Count - 1

    Set update = updateList.Item(I)

    WScript.Echo "Update found:", update.Title

  Next

  WScript.Echo

  updateDownloader.Updates = updateList
  updateDownloader.Priority = 3

  Set downloadResult = updateDownloader.Download()

  If downloadResult.ResultCode <> 2 Then

    WScript.Echo "Download failed with result code", downloadResult.ResultCode
    WScript.Echo

    WScript.Quit 1

  End If

  WScript.Echo "Download complete.  Installing updates ..."
  WScript.Echo

  updateInstaller.Updates = updateList

  Set installationResult = updateInstaller.Install()

  If installationResult.ResultCode <> 2 Then

    WScript.Echo "Installation failed with result code", installationResult.ResultCode

    For I = 0 to updateList.Count - 1

      Set updateInstallationResult = installationResult.GetUpdateResult(I)
      WScript.Echo "Result for " & updateList.Item(I).Title & " is " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(I).ResultCode

    Next

    WScript.Quit 1

  End If

  If installationResult.RebootRequired Then

    WScript.Echo "The system must be rebooted to complete installation."

    WScript.Quit 3

  End If

  WScript.Echo "Installation complete."

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Update API is quite powerful, however it is not easy to determine which update is acutally "important" - your code shows a very simple search for all updates that are not yet installed. You can list the update packages and query the properties of the IUpdate Interfaces (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386099(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can also have a look at WuInstall (there was a free version a while ago, but they put it off the website, now only a commercial version with a free trial is availalbe) - it does also utilize the Windows Update API in a command line tool. See http://www.wuinstall.com/ and http://help.wuinstall.com/en/index.html

Basically, you can do many (not all) things that WuInstall can do also with the Windows Update API, but it might save you a lot of time of programming and debugging.

What do you mean with "create a popup", by the way?

Comment: it creates multiple window in order to notify the user of any available updates. the code above does work but in order to all the updates avalible you have to update the window by clicking... not helpful with over 100 updates needed.

Comment: Only message boxes will pop up when updates are available if you use this VBScript [link] (http://superuser.com/questions/1152177/in-vbscript-i-need-a-code-to-subtract-1-from-searchresult-updates-count-so-tha/1152782#1152782).