# In VBScript, I need a code to subtract 1 from searchResult.Updates.Count, so that Count = 0 and WScript.Quit will be run consequently

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, vbscript, code

I already googled for hours but failed to find the answer.

```
'ServerSelection values
ssDefault = 0
ssManagedServer   = 1
ssWindowsUpdate   = 2
ssOthers          = 3

'InStr values
intSearchStartChar = 1

dim strTitle

Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

updateSearcher.ServerSelection = ssWindowsUpdate
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)

If update.Title = "Intel Corporation driver update for Intel(R) HD Graphics" Then 
I need a code on this line to subtract 1 from searchResult.Updates.Count, so that Count = 0 and WScript.Quit will be run consequently.
End If

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
WScript.Quit
End If

set objShell = createobject("wscript.shell")  
objShell.Run("ms-settings:windowsupdate") , 0

Next
WScript.Quit
```

The above VBScript checks for Windows updates. I want to remove some updates such as driver updates from `searchResult.Updates.Count`, so that `searchResult.Updates.Count = 0` and `WScript.Quit` will be run consequently. I want it to take no action when specified updates are found and take actions only when other updates are found.

Comment: You can either do `searchResult.Updates.Count = 0` or `searchResult.Updates.Count = searchResult.Updates.Count -1`

Comment: `searchResult.Updates.Count = 0` is not suitable because there could be other available updates that I want and thus cannot count as 0. `searchResult.Updates.Count = searchResult.Updates.Count -1` does not work at my end. Does it work at yours?

Comment: I see no reason it shouldn't.  Its your basic logic to reduce the value of a variable by 1, works in every programming language I have used (over 20) and you actually do the exact same thing when you do `For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1`.  If your for loop "works" then my suggestion should work.  If that doesn't work.  Create a variable set to the value of `searchResult.Updates.Count` and decrement by 1 that instead and (use that variable in your loop).

Comment: Do you mean `searchResult.Updates.Count = 0` reduces the value by 1? But it simply cannot be run at my end. An error message appears instead.

Comment: `searchResult.Updates.Count = searchResult.Updates.Count -1` cannot be run either. An error message appears.

Comment: "an error message appears" tells me nothing helpful.  No; of course setting a variable to 0 does not decrease it.  Subtracting it by 1 decreases it.  Did you try my three suggestion?  Setting a variable to the value of the .Count and decreasing the value that variable instead.

Comment: I have just posted a new script as an answer at the bottom of this page. Please have a look.

Comment: `.Count` is a read-only property. It tells you the number of elements in a collection/list. To “modify” it, you’d need to add/remove elements from the list. This may not be possible if it’s a read-only list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read duDE's above answer, I have thought up the following:

```
'ServerSelection values
ssDefault = 0
ssManagedServer   = 1
ssWindowsUpdate   = 2
ssOthers          = 3
'InStr values
intSearchStartChar = 1

Dim strTitle

Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()

updateSearcher.ServerSelection = ssWindowsUpdate
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")

If searchResult.Updates.Count = None Then 
WScript.Quit 
Else 
Dim value : value = searchResult.Updates.Count 
End If 

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)

'The following excluded updates have to be hidden via 'Show or hide updates' beforehand.
'Otherwise, they will be downloaded and installed by Windows Update.
If update.Title = "The full update title" Then Value = Value - 1
If update.Title = "The full update title" Then Value = Value - 1
If update.Title = "The full update title" Then Value = Value - 1

An_item = "KB2267602" 
Set Act=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
If instr(update.Title, An_item) <> 0 Then 
Act.Run("""C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"" ""-SignatureUpdate"""), 0
value = value - 1 
End If
Next

If Value = 0 Then 
WScript.Quit 
End If

result = MsgBox (_
"The number of available updates is（" & Value & "）." & vbNewLine &_
"Do you want to open【Windows Update】？", vbYesNo + vbQuestion,_
"【There are available updates.】")
Select Case result
Case vbYes
Act.run("ms-settings:windowsupdate")
Case vbNo
WScript.Quit
End Select
```

It works at my end. A dialog box will appear only if there are available updates to the exclusion of unwanted ones. Please tell me whether it works at your end or can be improved.

Comment: When this runs, it will install the updates you said you don't want, it does nothing to actually exclude anything from the update list

Comment: The script will NOT install anything. It will only open Windows Update when you click on 'Yes'. And you can use 'Show or hide updates' to hide unwanted updates before clicking on 'download' in Windows Update.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```
Dim nMyRes : nMyRes = 20

MsgBox "nMyRes before loop: " & nMyRes

For i = 0 To nMyRes-1
    If i = 5 Then nMyRes = nMyRes - 1
    If i = 10 Then nMyRes = nMyRes - 1
Next

MsgBox "nMyRes after loop: " & nMyRes
```

This code snippet works fine. In your case you have an object (searchResult) and I'm not sure you can change it.
That is why I would define a new variable and use it like this:

```
Dim nMyNewvar : nMyNewvar  = searchResult.Updates.Count - 1
' ...
' ...
For I = 0 To nMyNewvar  

' ...
If update.Title = "bla-bla" Then nMyNewvar = nMyNewvar - 1
```

[EDITED]

```
' Add this one row here
 Dim nMyNewvar : nMyNewvar  = searchResult.Updates.Count - 1
 'For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
 For I = 0 To nMyNewvar 
  Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)

  If update.Title = "bla-bla" Then 
   'I need a code on this line to subtract 1 from ....
   nMyNewvar = nMyNewvar - 1
 End If

  If nMyNewvar  = 0 Then
   WScript.Quit
  End If

  set objShell = createobject("wscript.shell")  
  objShell.Run("ms-settings:windowsupdate") , 0

Next
```

Comment: Into which part of my script should your code be added?

Comment: @MatthewWai - When you check the title.

Comment: @ duDE, I don't understand it. Could you give some clues?

Comment: @MatthewWai I have edited, do you understand it now? :)

Comment: Yesterday, when I was playing with the script, my Internet connection dropped out. I tried for hours to fix it but failed. Today I have clean-installed Windows 10 and can now access the Internet. I am now busy with other settings and installing software, so I have to delay studying the script.

Comment: I have just posted a new script as an answer at the bottom of this page. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
If update.Title = "Intel Corporation driver update for Intel(R) HD Graphics" Then 
    subtract 1 from searchResult.Updates.Count,
    so that Count = 0 and WScript.Quit will be run consequently.
    End If

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
WScript.Quit
End If
```

to:

```
If update.Title = "Intel Corporation driver update for Intel(R) HD Graphics" Then 
WScript.Quit
End If
```

However, it sounds like you are going add a list of things to this. In that case, you logic is wrong as it will stop execution after finding any one thing in the list. You will need to remove the item from the actual list somehow.

Also, you also cannot simply alter count: it is a read-only property that is set by the object, and it will not remove the item from the index. You are also running a for loop using it as a limit.

A better way to run a loop on a set of values that you are also altering is to use something like "while count > 0 do".

Microsoft has an example where they iterate through the list and if they want to download (after running some tests on each), they *add* the item to a second list that is passed to the updater.

Comment: I have just posted a new script as an answer at the bottom of this page. Please have a look.